# Is there a way where I can highlight the field/div of the focused input?

Tags: html, css, focus, highlight

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<style>
    input:focus { 
        background: yellow;
    }

    div:focus { 
        background: gray;
    }
</style>

    **This section must be highlighted whenever i run the code**
    <div> 
        SOME TEXT<input type = 'text' autofocus>
    </div>
    <div>
        SOME TEXT <input type = 'text'>
    </div> 

</html>
```

Comment: css? :focus? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/

Comment: Please read the [How to ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just pasting your code here without any explanation isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i tried something using jQuery, though there may be other ways to reach this result.

First i've made a class `.gray` which i use in the jquery part. And if you use this be sure to include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

**CSS**

```
input:focus { 
    background: yellow;
}

.gray {
    background:gray;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $('input').parent().removeClass("gray");
})

.focus(function() {     
    $(this).parent().addClass("gray")
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0v4LLLx/)

If you want you can replace the remove/addClass by `css('background', 'gray');`

> ***note*** this may not be supported in older browsers especially older versions of IE (below 10)

```css
input:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').blur(function() {
      $('input').parent().removeClass("gray");
    })

    .focus(function() {
      $(this).parent().addClass("gray")
    });

  });
</script>
<div>
  SOME TEXT
  <input type="text" value="" autofocus>
</div>
<div>
  SOME TEXT
  <input type="text" value="">
  </div
```

Comment: I know what to do now. Thanks a lot :)